# Conditional Automapper Doesn't Work For MapFrom

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I use conditional map for two situation and one of them works and other doesn't works.
My entity is here

```
public class Form
{
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping configuration code is here, if "UserId" different from null it should be get from relation otherwise it gets from the table.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Form, FormDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.UserId != null ? c.User.Name : c.Name));
```

And this code works, there is no problem.

```
var forms = _unitOfWork.FormRepository
                        .GetConversations(mainFormId)
                        .ProjectTo<FormDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                        .ToList();
//it gets "Name" fine from relation mapping 
Console.Write(forms[0].Name)
```

but this code doesn't work, problem is here.

```
var formDto = _mapper.Map<FormDto>(_unitOfWork.FormRepository.GetForm(mainFormId));
//The "Name" property is empty but it should be get it from relation
Console.Write(formDto.Name)
```

What's your suggestion please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Uppps, I forgot virtual keyword. It's work fine now.

```
public class Form
{
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```